# When solving this differential equation why should we look for absolutely continuous solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, absolute-continuity, subgradient

Why does the author here suggest that we look for absolutely continuous curves as solutions to the following differential inclusion (or LESS generally a differential equation)?

[image]

Here the $\partial F$ is the subgradient. The source is [Wasserstein Gradient Flows by Santambrogio](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03890).

Comment: One possibility is that absolutely continuous functions are exactly the functions for which the fundamental theorem of calculus$$u(t) = u(0) + \int_{0}^{t} u'(s) \; \text{d}s \qquad \forall t \in [0, T]$$ holds, in particular, they are differentiable almost everywhere and their derivative is absolutely integrable.